# Получить все TTable из TDatabase

Tags: c++, c++builder

Как получить список всех объектов `ТTable`, которые связаны с `TDatabase` через свойство `DatabaseName`? Свойство `TDatabase::TDatabaseDataSets` возвращает лишь активные (`active=true`) таблицы, а мне как раз и нужно получить неактивные таблицы и сделать их активными.

Comment: Не дайте дураком помереть! Что такое "активные таблицы"?

Comment: @BuilderC я же написал: у которых установлено свойство `active=true`. И если подключить к такой таблице `TDbGrid`, то в нём будут отображаться данные из базы данных, иначе не будут. Может быть, правильнее было бы сказать: подключенные к БД таблицы, хотя тоже звучит не очень.